# How can I reload my XKB configuration without restarting my computer or logging back in

Tags: keyboard, xorg, keyboard-layout, xkb

I made a cool, little script that will edit my `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` file automatically. It is useful when I want to switch between a Mac or Windows keyboard.

The one problem I've encountered is that I have to log out and then log back in after editing the file in order for the edited configuration to take effect.

I've tried deleting my xkb cache (`/var/lib/xkb/*.xkm`), but that did work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: editing the `.../symbols/pc` file regularly isn't recommended.  XKB probably already knows the differences; you just need to know what to tell it to  load.  if these are different physical keyboards you're switching between, specifying a model will probably do what you want:  `setxkbmap -model apple -layout us` vs `-model pc105`.

Answer (score 26):

Solution. Run this command. Of course, you could change "us" to your desired keyboard layout.

`setxkbmap -layout us`

Comment: Does what you say. The key ingredient for me was an additional `-variant foo`.

Comment: This actually reload "us" keyboard, but unfortunately disables other keyboard layouts (in case of multi-keyboard use).

Comment: @Name you can set variants and other things as you like, you can also specify 1+ layouts to switch between. You can find more info in `man setxkbmap`.

Comment: Thanks. This reloads my changes in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev`. Good.

Comment: Quick note, if you want to select a nondefault variant for a language you can write `setxkbmap 'fr(bepo)'` where `fr` is your language and `bepo` the variant name in the symbol file (not sure if variant is the correct terminology anyway).

Answer (score 12):

It's answered in Unix Stack Exchange:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290449/how-to-reload-xserver-after-a-change-in-keyboard-layout

Basically, you do this:

```
sudo udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change
```

It is also mentioned that the following might be sufficient, please comment on what system setup it alone helped:

```
# For Ubuntu < 16.04
service keyboard-setup restart
# For Ubuntu >= 16.04
systemctl restart keyboard-setup
```

You might come across other answers suggesting you delete `/var/lib/xkb/*.xkm`. That would be an outdated suggestion. At least in Ubuntu, this directory wasn't used for this purpose for quite a few years.

Comment: That doesn’t actually “reload” the keyboard layout, at least not the current one. When I tried on 18.04, it didn’t pick up any of the changes made in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`; only `sudo udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change` (also mentioned in the answer and a comment to it) did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Run follwing command to reload XKB:

```
sudo setxkbmap
```

don't set -layout option. just execute above command.