# 3rd level key has no effect, how do I make it work or are there any other good ways to type less common characters quickly?

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, gnome-shell

I installed the gnome tweak tool, and went to "Additional layout options". There are several possible keys that can be assigned to choose 3rd level, I tried right <kbd>Alt</kbd> and right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and both of these seem to have no effect at all, that is, they don't change which characters are typed. (I tried to press them at the same time with a key, and also tried to press them before a key, both results in no modification; I also tried 2 text editors, the built in one and Sublime Text, and there's no difference too).

"Compose" key seems to work but this method is too slow and hard to remember and I don't like it.

So how do I fix the 3rd level functionality?

The input source I'm currently using is "English (US)".

Comment: Which keyboard layout are you using?

Comment: @pomsky can't find any place where it's called a layout, but there are 2 input sources, and the input source I'm currently using is "English (US)".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typing guillemets (angle quotes, «») in Russian and English keyboards](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061647/typing-guillemets-angle-quotes-in-russian-and-english-keyboards) . If you want to use typographic symbols you should enable this option in GNOME Tweaks. It works on US keyboard.

Comment: Another possible solutions may be this one: https://askubuntu.com/a/1075707/991004

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard "English (US)" layout doesn't have any characters associated to the 3rd level key, so it's not surprising that the key does nothing.

Add "*English (US, international with dead keys)*" or something similar to your input sources and use it to access some extra characters.

Comment: I used to have dead keys working (16.04) and suddenly it stopped, I fixed it going to Keyboard > Input Sources and  removing  English (US) as the second choice below the 'dead keys' one. Just posting here for visibility.