# Hyper-key u --> Like Arrow-Up

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, xmodmap, remapping

I made CapsLock the Hyper-key via `gnome-tweaks`

Sorry, I have only the german screenshot. "Feststelltaste" means "CapsLock"

[image: gnome-tweaks-capslock-de]

Now I would like to map

- `Hyper-u` to `Arrow-Up`
- `Hyper-n` to `Arrow-Down`
- `Hyper-i` to `Page-Up`
- `Hyper-m` to `Page-down`
- `Hyper-j` to `Pos1`
- `Hyper-ö` to `End` (on my german layout this character is right to "l")

It would be great if this could be done by doing config in $HOME.

For example via .xmodmaprc

Related question: [Make arrow-up/down, Pos1, End, Del ... more easy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1382478/make-arrow-up-down-pos1-end-del-more-easy)

## Every solution is welcome

I am open for every solution which works. Maybe there is way to solve this via eBPF or an own uinput-device?

## Background

I like the then fingers touch typing. I am happy with my QWERTZ layout for a-Z. But these special keys always make me leave the comfortable position with the pointer fingers on "F" and "J".

Comment: Maybe python-libevdev helps: https://python-libevdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#basic-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind a GUI application, [input-remapper](https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper/blob/main/readme/development.md) has always worked well for me with various input devices and is also available on APT.

It runs as a daemon in the background and reinjects your inputs using evdev, so there's probably a more elegant solution out there, but could be useful as a last resort or if you want to change input mappings often.

Comment: Thank you very much! input-remapper is great. I have been looking for a tool like this for years. See my article "ten flying fingers":  https://github.com/guettli/ten-flying-fingers

Answer (score 1):

When Caps Lock behavior is set to default, i.e, "Disabled"

[image: Caps Lock behavior set to default]

create `.xmodmap` file with below content,
keycode 66 is the Physical Caps Lock Key on My Keyboard

```
clear lock
keycode 66 = Mode_switch
add lock = Mode_switch
keycode 30 = u U Up
keycode 57 = n N Down
keycode 31 = i I Prior
keycode 58 = m M Next
```

Run

```
xmodmap .xmodmap
```

Comment: I get this error message from `xmodmap` X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  118 (X_SetModifierMapping)
  Value in failed request:  0x17
  Serial number of failed request:  17
  Current serial number in output stream:  17

Comment: Ignore it n check the key combination if it's Working or not. I got the error but combination worked.

Comment: It works in gedit. But not in Chromium and not in PyCharm :-(

Comment: @guetti that worked for me in chromium in my Ubuntu 20.04, I dont know about PyCharm. if you are exclusively looking for PyCharm.. there may be a different way to achieve?

Comment: it's very old, but maybe read [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=32304) about chromium

Comment: Today I tried it again, but it does not work in PyCharm and not in vscode. But it works in Chrome and on the terminal. Nevertheless I need a solution which works in PyCharm and vscode.