# Reloading keyboard layout after editing XKB symbols in Waylay on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, wayland, xkb

I'm creating a custom layout, currently experimenting by editing /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us

Logging out and logging in reloads the keyboard.

But Is there anyway to reload keyboard layouts without logging on and off?

None of the solutions below work for me with Wayland on Ubuntu 20.04. Unless I am mistaken.
[How can I reload my XKB configuration without restarting my computer or logging back in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968107/how-can-i-reload-my-xkb-configuration-without-restarting-my-computer-or-logging)